# Turn binary number into string of words

Tags: string-manipulation, binary

I don't actually have any code for this, as I have no real idea how to do it. I have a large binary number combination that I know turns into some sort of string. How would I go about translating it?

Comment: How do you know it becomes a string? Is it a code?

Comment: You really have to explain this better.  What is a "binary number"?  Can you show an example?  How does it map to a string?

Comment: Where did the "large binary number combination that ... turns into some sort of string" come from?

Comment: This question is too broad. The conversion from binary to string can be anything from @BobHanlon 's answer to converting binary to Unicode characters.

Answer (score 10):

```
bin = 1011011;

words = (bin // IntegerDigits) /. {1 -> "one", 0 -> "zero"};

(str = StringJoin[Riffle[words, " "]]) // InputForm

(*  "one zero one one zero one one"  *)

Speak[str]
```

Comment: I love this so much

Comment: Haha... that's the funniest answer I ever seen :)